# SOAP web service in .NET Core 7 : bug fix : web service run, error import reference from client

Tags: c#, soap, .net-7.0

I created a SOAP web service application in .NET Core 7, creating reference from a wsdl file. The SOAP web service runs, but when I try  to import reference, I get this error:

> If you were trying to create a client, the problem may be that the metadata documents do not contain valid contracts or services or that all contracts/services are present in --reference assemblies. Verify that you have passed all metadata documents to the tool.
> The operation has been completed.
>
> Failed to add service references. The index (zero-based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

Are there some attribute that I have to add in class

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.1.0")]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.SoapTypeAttribute(Namespace="XXXXXX")]
public partial class Name_of_class
```

What are the attribute that I have to add?

Comment: Probably none.  Looks like you are using looking at classes that were generated by the xsd.exe tool which generates a lot of unnecessary attributes.  The only one I usually use is [XmlRoot(ElementName="abc", Namespace="xyz")]